# How to set-up openGL in a more Data Driven Enviornment, with an Entity/Component/System Architecture?

Tags: c++, opengl, lua, game-engine

So i have been writing a game Engine for linux , using OpenGL,SDL2, and Lua (so far). I plan on incorporating OpenAL possibly for audio, however that is irrelevant

I have been having a hard time grasping the best way i can set this up. Maybe i dont understand the idea behind it.  In my project i have a Shader object, as well as ShaderVariable object (which is basically a custom variant class), and ShaderProgram object. The shader program contains up to 6 shaders ( for each part of the pipeline). My Shader object loads the shader into a gluint, and has a isCompiled and isLinked boolean variable. Amongst these there is also a vector of ShaderVariable objects. When the GLSL code is loaded, the std::vector *m_attributes gets pushed back with a new shaderVariable object ( consisting of the name, and the type). How should i set up rendering if the specifications may differ between shaders that have not been made yet? ( the ones the end-user will be writing)

Another question i have is : Do those consist of variables in a vertex specification?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to build your own ECS.
That's a pretty deep subject.

It also sounds like you want a combination of OOP and component based modelling within your ECS.

Start by mapping out a few interfaces like IComponent, and IEntity then build some base types and work up from there.